# How do I set specific origin for request header on Cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, request-headers

I'm currently developing app that works with some external services and that service does not accept null, undefined nor file:// origin, so I need to set request origin other than those. What can I do to set request origin for request header on Cordova?

PS. I need to set a specific origin for request header.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version on Cordova, you either need

(cordova-ios < 6)
https://github.com/oracle/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr

(cordova-ios >= 6)
https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for replying late.
Is there any solution for Android?

Comment: There is no file issue with android

Comment: Oh... Didn't know that... Thanks for answering!

Comment: Just validate the answer :)